# DLL load failed while importing QtGui

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt6

I successfully installed PyQt6 module last night and I used this line of code for my first qt window :

```
from PyQt6.QtGui import QIcon
```

and it worked perfectly and without error.
Today I installed pyqt6-tools too for using qt designer
And now when I try to run the exact same file from last night I face this error :

```
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing QtGui: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

I don't know that it is related to the installation of pyqt6-tools module or not so I mentioned it.
My python version is 3.9.7

Can anyone help with this ?
what should I do about this ?

Comment: How about uninistalling pyqt6-tools (and perhaps also reinstalling pyqt6, if that got trashed by the aforementioned install)?

Comment: it didnt work :((

Answer (score 4):

1. Uninstall all modules related to PyQt6.

`pip uninstall -y PyQt6 pyqt6-plugins PyQt6-Qt6 PyQt6-sip pyqt6-tools qt6-applications qt6-tools`

2. Reinstall PyQt6.

`pip install PyQt6`

Comment: This solution also works with the same error for PyQt6-Charts